# Start with Debugging fails after upgrade from .NET5 to .NET6 on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-5, .net-6.0

I upgraded my WPF project from .NET5 to .NET6. When I try to run the project it gives `Unable to attach to CoreCLR. Operation not supported`

But, I am able to run Without Debugging.

I tried to clean and update Nuget Packages to .NET6. Also, removed the `obj` and `bin` folders. These didn't solve the problem.

How can I re-enable Debugging? Thanks.

[image: Unable to debug]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to change .NET5 `<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>` to setting below:

```
<PublishSingleFile Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">true</PublishSingleFile>
```

After this change, you'll able to run with Debugging.

This issue mentioned and solved on these topics. You may check the details.

1. https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/5677
2. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/45382